# \cite that tolerates whitespace?

Tags: spacing, citing, cite-package

Is there a package that provides a variant of the `\cite` command that tolerates arbitrary whitespace? That is, I would like to be able to write something like

```
\cite{foo, bar, baz}
```

or

```
\cite{
    foo, bar, baz,
    baf, bah, bam
}
```

without any ill effect.

To keep things interesting, it should work flawlessly with other commonly used packages such as `cite`, `natbib`, and `hyperref`, and it should also work *without* those packages.

---

**Edit:** Examples...

test.bib:

```
@MISC{bar,
    author={Bar Bar},
    title={Bar},
    year={1988}
}

@MISC{foo,
    author={Foo Foo},
    title={Foo},
    year={1988}
}
```

---

test1.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{foo, bar }.

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Here `pdflatex test1` works OK but `bibtex test1` gives the following error:

```
White space in argument---line 2 of file test1.aux
 : \citation{foo,bar
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
```

---

test2.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \cite{foo, bar }.

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Again, `pdflatex test2` works OK but `bibtex test2` produces the following error:

```
White space in argument---line 3 of file test2.aux
 : \citation{bar
 :               }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
```

---

test3.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
    \cite{foo, bar }.

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

This seems to work fine! But naturally it has all the side-effects of the `cite` package as well, which isn't always compatible with other packages.

Comment: As I recall, the only place it doesn't tolerate whitespace is before the closing `}`.

Comment: @TH.: Thanks, I have never investigated exactly where it tolerates and where it doesn't; I have just noticed that sometimes something fails badly if I have whitespace in \cite.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry if I'm being stupid, but for me the simple answer is: It works if I use the `cite` package. (This works flawlessly with `cite`, but it doesn't work without `cite` ;-).)

Comment: Gah! I *knew* there had to be something much simpler! In fact loading either `cite` or `natbib` both solve the problem.

Comment: Really?? Whitespace problems with `\cite` and `natbib` was what actually inspired me to post this question!

Comment: If you have a minimal example please add it to your question. The small example I tried seems to work fine.

Comment: Sure, I have clearly been too lazy with the formulation of the question and doing my homework, I'll try to put together some examples soon.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work with `natbib`. I just changed `cite` to `natbib` and ignored all the compilation errors when running for the second time :S. Anyway, I know that my alternative solution is not nice, but at least it does work with `natbib`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I guess that for other people struggling with the same issue, the suggestion to use the `cite` package is the best answer so far, so I'll accept it for now. I guess an ideal solution would be a package that provides only a selected subset of the functionality of `cite`, so that one one could pick and choose which features to take. My biggest problem with `cite` is that it occasionally tries to be far too clever, and hence I have recently used natbib more often.

Answer (score 6):

So I decided to give it a go. The problem seems to be with any spaces *after* each individual entry and before the `,` or the closing `}`. If you can avoid spaces there then that's probably the best thing to do.

If you really insist in being able to have spaces anywhere in the list, then I was able to come up with the following very hackish solution.

```
\makeatletter
\def\tok@scan#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \let\tok@next\relax
  \else
    \edef\my@list{\my@list#1}%
    \let\tok@next\tok@scan
  \fi
  \tok@next
}
\newcommand{\@strip}[2]{%
  \def\my@list{}\tok@scan#2\relax\let#1\my@list}
\newcommand{\Cite}[1]{\@strip\@args{#1}\cite\@args}
\makeatother
```

Which allows you then to write

```
\Cite{  paper1  ,  paper2,  paper3  }
```

The short explanation is that `\@strip` will take two arguments: a command name (`\@args` in the example) and some arbitrary argument. It will then strip away all spaces in the argument and store the result in the command you provided, then you can use `\@args` as a valid argument of, say, `\cite`.

Of course, if you use `natbib` or other packages for citations you will have to define corresponding macros such as `\Citet` and `\Citep` with appropriate interfaces (e.g. optional arguments, etc.).

I really hope someone could come up with something better/easier.